# Is checking the length of a file thread safe?

Tags: python, atomic

I have a commercial application writing data to a file in an incremental order.
I would like to copy the file over to a database at regular intervals.

To do so, I plan to retrieve the length of the file, and copy up till a few bytes shorter than the retrieved length. In so doing, I hope that the application will be able to write to the file without noticing any changes.

Does retrieving the length of the file with say `os.path.getsize` interrupt the writing process?

Comment: The answer to this question will depend on at least the OS used, whether the "commercial application" ever seeks backwards, and possibly any networked filesystems in play.

Comment: OS used is windows, no networked filesystems, I cannot guarantee, but I think the commercial application does not seek backward all the way. thus i was hoping to set a byte count limit from the back of the file

Comment: Should work then. Does "the commercial application" do some kind of file rotation (ie start a new file when the current one is too large) or something?

Comment: No, it starts a new file according to the clock. So retrieving file length does not interrupt the writing process?

Comment: It does not. Neither should reading from it.

Comment: Any sane OS/FS will have all its file operations thread-safe, in the sense that an operation will run and complete without crash. How do you expect anything to work otherwise?

Comment: @Tian define "interrupt". Since the length of a file has to be written to the disk as well, then it depends on OS, FS and the disk itself. For example for HDD, most certainly only one IO operation runs at a time. But there are also caches involved. So in worst case scenario the answer is "yes, only one read/write operation (including length read) at a time". But on average, with caches involved, this will most likely be parallelized.

Comment: @freakish thanks for the input. My main concern is that the datafile being written to will not get corrupted

Comment: @Tian no, corruption won't happen, unless there are multiple writers. And even with multiple writers the worst thing that can happen is garbage content. As I've mentioned earlier: all FS operations are expected to be thread-safe. Otherwise it would be a disaster. After all lots of background processes access fs at unpredictable moments.

Comment: @freakish does that mean i can go ahead and apply `shutil.copyfile` on the datafile being written on without any fear of corruption?

Comment: @Tian again: it depends on what you mean by "corruption". Say you have a file with content `012`, you run `shutil.copyfile` while another process overwrites the file with `abc`. The result of copy can be any of the following: `012`, `a12`, `ab2`, `abc` (well, that's actually not true, since writes to a certain size are atomic, but you get the point). In order to copy a file in a consistent way you have to make sure that all writes are actually atomic appends. This is not so easy done unfortunately. Just reading size and copying up to size is not enough. I advice using a database.

Comment: @freakish in the context of this question, the application only appends to the data file. From your comment I take it that as long as there is no overwriting, the copy is safe?

Comment: @Tian again: what exactly do you mean by "safe"? Say you have an empty file and a process appends `abc` to it while you copy it. The result can be any of: "empty file", `a`, `ab`, `abc`. So as long as you can deal with this "not necessarily correct ending" then I suppose this is safe. For example if each line is a JSON, then you are safe. Since partial JSONs are not allowed, you can remember the last correct JSON and start from that place next time.

Comment: @freakish thanks for the explanation! For my purposes this is fine.